# What to use for trasfoming xml using xslt, js and css

Tags: xslt, browser

I want to transform an xml file, display its treeview on a html page. I have downloaded an example, it has xslt, js, css and also some images. I used xmlspy to do the transformation, but it didn't work.

Could anyone please tell me how to do the transformation?

Comment: Perhaps some links of what you downloaded might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find it easier (as I do) to do as much in the browser as poss take a look at Johann Burkard's xslt.js:

http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/

You can do/test your transformation right in the browser :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing [this is the example](http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/treeview/html/) you're using. In which case, you shouldn't have to use XMLSpy to do the transformation. A newer browser will have an XSLT processor built-in! Try using the latest version [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com) or [IE](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/ie/default.mspx)!

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has a [good explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) on how to Transform XML using XSL.

**[EDIT]** After re-reading your question, it seems that you are looking for a tool to apply XSL to your XML file and which outputs the result? Have you already tried [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en)?